# Saving a function pointer in member of a class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am making a menu bar that takes in menu items. I want the window that holds the menu bar to decide what the behaviour of a menu item will be. So I want the window to pass a function to the menu item.

My best attempt is getting me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MenuItem::setBehaviour(void (MyWindow::*)())'
```

Here is MenuItem.h:

```
class MenuItem{
public:
    typedef void (sf::RenderWindow::*function_type)();

    MenuItem(sf::RenderWindow* win); // window that holds the menu bar

    void setBehaviour(function_type f); // I want to be able to change the behaviour
                                        // to reuse the menu item
    void action(); // use the function

private:
    sf::RenderWindow* m_window;
    function_type     m_function;
};
```

MenuItem.cpp

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(sf::RenderWindow* win) : m_window(win)
{
    //ctor
}

void MenuItem::setBehaviour(function_type f)
{
     m_function = f;
}

void MenuItem::action()
{
    (m_window->*m_function)();
}
```

The window that adds the menu bar:

```
class MyWindow : public sf::RenderWindow
{
    //...
    void close();
};
```

And the window's cpp file:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow() : sf::RenderWindow(...)
{
    //...
    MenuItem item(this);
    item.setBehaviour(&MyWindow::close); // error!
    //...
}

//...

void MyWindow::close()
{
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: Well, the function pointer you try to  pass there isn't  a member of `sf::RenderWindow` but comes from a derived class.

Comment: Ah... I didn't see your comment until now. Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two answers given were over my head a little. I spent some time looking at Jan's std::function and learned a little more in the process. Here's what I did wrong:

The functions for MenuItem will come from MyWindow, not sf::RenderWindow, so I need to forward declare MyWindow and change all the sf::RenderWindows to MyWindow.

```
class MyWindow; // fix: forward declaration
class MenuItem{
    public:

    typedef void (MyWindow::*function_type)(); // fix

    MenuItem(MyWindow* win); // fix

    void setBehaviour(function_type f);

    void action();

private:
    MyWindow* m_window; // fix
    function_type     m_function;
};
```

MenuItem.cpp

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(MyWindow* win) : m_window(win) // fix
{
    //ctor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to solve that is to make `MenuItem` a templated class:

```
template<typename RenderWindow>
class MenuItem{
public:
    typedef void (RenderWindow::*function_type)();

    MenuItem::MenuItem(RenderWindow* win) 
    : m_window(win) {
        std::static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<sf::RenderWindow,RenderWindow>()
                           ,"RenderWindow must be derived from sf::RenderWindow.");
    }

    void setBehaviour(function_type f) {
        m_function = f;
    }

    void action() {
        m_window->*m_function)();
    }

private:
    RenderWindow*     m_window;
    function_type     m_function;
};
```

Omit the `MenuItem.cpp` file completely.

You can instantiate and access a `MenuItem` like

```
MyWindow myWindow;
MenuItem<MyWindow> closeWindow(myWindow);
menuItem.setBehavior(MyWindow::close);

// ...
menuItem.action();
```

then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::function` for that:

```
// MenuItem.h
#include <functional>

class MenuItem
{
    public:
        using function_type = std::function<void()>;
        auto setBehaviour(function_type f) -> void;
        auto action() -> void;

    private:
        function_type m_function;
};

// MenuItem.cpp
auto MenuItem::setBehaviour(function_type f) -> void
{
    m_function = f;
}

auto MenuItem::action() -> void
{
    m_function();
}

// MyWindow.cpp
#include <functional>

MyWindow::MyWindow() : sf::RenderWindow(...)
{
    MenuItem item(this);
    item.setBehaviour(std::bind(&MyWindow::close, this));
}

auto MyWindow::close() -> void
{
    // do something
}
```